# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Get modified or added files only

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that executes a Powershell task to create artifacts for each changed file after a pull request is submitted. However, I am not able to return modified/new files in order to create these artifacts. When I test locally I have no problem grabbing the modified file name, but within the pipeline itself the returned result is blank/empty:

```
$changes = git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter=M origin/master --name-only -- .
```

Full .yml Code:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

jobs:
- job: get_changed_files
  steps:  
   - task: PowerShell@2
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
         $targetfolder = "$(Build.StagingDirectory)" + "/"
         
         function CopyFiles{
             param( [string]$source )
         
             $target = $targetfolder + $source
         
             New-Item -Force $target
             copy-item $source $target -Force
         }
         $changes = git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter=M origin/master --name-only -- .
         write-host "test"
         $changes
         if ($changes -is [string]){ CopyFiles $changes }
         else
         {
             if ($changes -is [array])
             {       
                 foreach ($change in $changes){ CopyFiles $change }
             }
         }
   - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
     inputs:
      pathToPublish: $(Build.StagingDirectory)
      artifactName: MyChangedFiles
```

Update: I switched my diff command to the following: `git diff  --name-only --relative --diff-filter=AM HEAD^ HEAD` and confirmed my pipeline now works as expected.

Comment: Is the pipeline running against `origin/master` already? If yes then there would be no changes...

Comment: The pipeline is triggered on pushes to master, yes. However, even if I create a new branch and merge to master.. my script does not find any differences.

Comment: It sounds like you are comparing up to date `master` with `origin/master` every time, so they'll be the same. Side Note, what merge strategy to you use when completing PRs? (Merge, squash, rebase, semi-linear merge, or maybe it isn't always the same one?)

Comment: That could very well be true as I am a novice in proper GIT usage. How could I compare up to date master with the current PR? I am using the default MERGE (No fast forward) only because that is the default in DevOps and I am simply testing.

Comment: If you are running your pipeline *after* the PR is *completed* and merged into `master`, then there is no "current" PR. But since you are using merge (or semi-linear merge which would also work), you could do something like `git diff @ @~1` which will compare the tip commit (the merge commit) with the tip commit's first parent commit (which is what `master` looked like before the PR was completed).

Comment: I believe you described exactly what I was thinking, but wasn't able to confirm because my knowledge of GIT is rather limited. I will post the updated GIT DIFF command I am using, which is now working. However, is what I am doing good practice or do you need further context in order to accurately reply?

Comment: I think it should work fine for your stated scenario. I do something very similar for gated checkins against in-progress PRs using the `pull/12345/merge` behind-the-scenes refs. I've added an answer based on our discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are running the pipeline against `master` after the Pull Request is completed. At that moment the pipeline is comparing `master` with `origin/master` and they are always equal, so the diff will not find anything.

An alternative way to do the diff is to compare your HEAD commit with it's first parent commit, like this:

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD
# or using @ syntax for HEAD
git diff @~1 @
# or using merge commit syntax
git diff @^ @
```

Comparing these 2 commits will only work if your PRs are completed using Merge, Semi-Linear Merge, or Squash Merge.

If you use a rebase and fast-forward PR completion strategy, you won't know from looking at the branch history how many commits are "new", so you'll need to store the commit ID you were on the last time you ran the pipeline as the starting point.

**Side Note:** if multiple PRs can be completed between pipeline runs, then it's possible you'll miss some changes. Some ways to overcome this are to queue up pipeline runs such that each run happens against a specific commit and no completed PR is skipped, or to save off the last commit ID that the pipeline was run against, as described for a rebase and fast-forward completion strategy.

Comment: If a user submits a PR and the build pipeline is triggered on the push to master, why would it matter when the release pipeline was ran as that would reference the stored artifacts, which would include all the changed files.

Comment: @DataDill It probably(?) would be fine but depends on how it's implemented. For example, suppose PR 1 is completed and creates merge commit 1 on `master`, and PR 2 is completed 1 second later and creates commit 2 on `master`. If the pipeline is triggered twice, and runs once against commit 1 and once against commit 2, then it's fine. But if the pipeline takes a few seconds to start and it's not against each commit (for example if it runs just once, or if both runs look at `origin/master` instead of the specific merge commit), then it likely would miss some changes.

Comment: Note, from the sounds of it your pipeline will work fine (runs on every new change to `master` and against the HEAD commit at that instant). I only mentioned the possible miss because not all pipelines are implemented that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$changes = git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AMCR HEAD^ HEAD .
```

The above command will work *only* if we fetch more than one commit, so we need to configure depth in order to work; otherwise, the pipeline with throw an error with "HEAD^".... bla bla...

[image]